ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" POSTGRESQL JAVA SPRINGBOOT
this is my repository

@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT a.kjab, a.kuk, a.jablongname AS jabatan, a.longname AS unit_kerja, a.jbisnon AS klasifikasi, \r\n" + //
                        "a.nama AS tipe_kantor, COALESCE(a.user_pembuat, 'SYSTEM') AS user_pembuat, a.actionlog AS actionlog, \r\n" + //
                        "COALESCE(a.fullname, 'SYSTEM') AS fullname, COALESCE(CAST(a.usertimelog AS VARCHAR), '-') AS usertimelog, a.sasaran_kinerja, a.indikator, \r\n" + //
                        "a.status \r\n" + //
                        "FROM ( \r\n" + //
                        "  SELECT i.kindikator, j.jablongname, u.longname, j.jbisnon, t.longname AS nama, i.user_pembuat, \r\n" + //
                        "  COALESCE(at2.actionlog, 'I') AS actionlog, e.fullname, at2.usertimelog, u.kuk, j.kjab, ci.sasaran_kinerja, ci.indikator, \r\n" + //
                        "  CASE WHEN ci.sasaran_kinerja IS NOT NULL AND ci.indikator IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS status \r\n" + //
                        "  FROM master.jabatan j \r\n" + //
                        "    INNER JOIN master.unitkerja u ON u.kuk = j.kuk \r\n" + //
                        "    INNER JOIN indikator i ON (i.kdjab = j.kjab OR (i.kdjab IS NULL AND i.kuk = u.parent)) AND i.is_active = TRUE \r\n" + //
                        "    LEFT JOIN audit_trail at2 ON CAST(jsonb_extract_path(CAST(at2.new_data AS jsonb), 'kindikator') AS INT) = i.kindikator AND at2.kmenu = 65 \r\n" + //
                        "    INNER JOIN master.tipekantor t ON t.ktipekantor = u.ktipekantor \r\n" + //
                        "    LEFT JOIN roles.users us ON us.username = i.user_pembuat \r\n" + //
                        "    LEFT JOIN master.employee e ON e.nrp = us.nrp \r\n" + //
                        "    LEFT JOIN ( \r\n" + //
                        "      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.ktargetkinerja) AS sasaran_kinerja, COUNT(DISTINCT i.kindikator) AS indikator, u.kuk, i.kdjab \r\n" + //
                        "      FROM indikator i \r\n" + //
                        "      JOIN master.unitkerja u ON u.kuk = i.kuk \r\n" + //
                        "      JOIN targetkinerja t ON t.ktargetkinerja = i.ktargetkinerja \r\n" + //
                        "      LEFT JOIN master.jabatan j ON j.kjab = i.kdjab AND j.jbisnon = i.jbisnon \r\n" + //
                        "      JOIN perspektif p ON i.kperspektif = p.kperspektif \r\n" + //
                        "      GROUP BY u.kuk, i.kdjab \r\n" + //
                        "    ) AS ci ON ci.kdjab = i.kdjab \r\n" + //
                        ") AS a \r\n" + //
                        "WHERE a.longname ILIKE CONCAT('%', :unitKerja, '%') \r\n" + //
                        "AND a.jablongname ILIKE CONCAT('%', :jabatan, '%') \r\n" + //
                        "AND a.jbisnon ILIKE CONCAT('%', :klasifikasi, '%') \r\n" + //
                        "AND (:isActive IS NULL OR a.status = :isActive) \r\n" + //
                        "AND a.actionlog ILIKE CONCAT('%', :actionLog, '%') \r\n" + //
                        "ORDER BY a.kuk ASC, a.jablongname ASC",nativeQuery = true)
        Page<Map<String, Object>> ListMasterDataIndikator(@Param("unitKerja") String unitKerja, 
                        @Param("jabatan") String jabatan, @Param("klasifikasi") String klasifikasi, 
                        @Param("isActive") Boolean isActive, @Param("actionLog") String actionLog, 
                        Pageable pageable);

which is driving me crazy. Can anyone please tell me what i might have missed? i have try some solution but i cant find solution

I would start by copy/pasting that string literal to a System.out.println call, so you can see just the SQL without all the extra cruft.

And then run that SQL in a client to see if it gives the same error. By the way, the computer can parse the SQL just as well without the line breaks, i.e. the \r\n.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Don't just put the error message in the title. It should be in the body of the question. Is that the full message? Is there a stack trace or something else?

The SQL is impossible to read and to understand, that's exactly why you have a bug somewhere hiding in this code. Drop all the garbage and most likely your IDE already shows you the error.
